# Grab photos from Flickr

Tags: javascript, json, angular.js

I wrote the following code for a coding challenge I was given and it received the following criticism:  `it was quite a beginner attempt using Angular.`

```
<body>

 <div id="view" ng-view ></div>

<script >
  angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']).
  config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
      when('/',{                        //our main page
         templateUrl:'main.html', 
         controller:'myController' 
      }).
      when('/1',{                    //main page again; however, this is a little trick as to make the infinite scroll working  
         templateUrl:'main.html', 
         controller:'myController' 
      }).
      when('/2',{                    //our results page
         templateUrl:'results.html', 
         controller:'resultsController' 
      }).
      when('/3',{                   //main page when coming back from results page; we use another hash as not to reload data in that case
         templateUrl:'main.html', 
         controller:'myController' 
      });
  }).
  //This custom service keeps track of the already loaded photos as not to be lost 
  service('myService',function(){
      this.photos=[];
  }).
  //This is the controller for the main page
  controller('myController', ['$scope','$http', 'myService','$timeout', function ($scope,$http,myService,$timeout) {
    $scope.photos=myService.photos;
    //As not to download new photos and just present the previous ones when we use the GO BACK link 
    if (window.location.hash!=='#/3')  
    { 
      //Getting JSON data and pushing it inside myService.photos array
      var url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK";
      $http.jsonp(url).then(function(response) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.photos,response.data.items);},function(){alert('Error retrieving JSON data')}
      );
    }
      $scope.phototitle=function(title){
          if ($.trim(title).length === 0)
             return "Untitled";
          else if (title.length<=20)
             return title
          else   
             return title.substring(0,20).concat('...');   
      };
      $scope.insertcommas=function(tags){
          var arr=tags.split(' ');
          return arr.join(', ');
      };

    $scope.flag=false;
    //the following function creates myService.results array, according to tags criteria, which will be passed to the results page.
    //It is invoking with button Search 
    $scope.results=function(){
      myService.results=[];  
      var arr=$scope.searchTag.split(','); 
      for (var i=0;i<myService.photos.length;i++)
        for (var j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
          if ( myService.photos[i].tags.split(' ').indexOf($.trim(arr[j]).toLowerCase())>-1) {
             myService.results.push(myService.photos[i]); 
             break;
          }
        }
      if (myService.results.length!==0)  
        window.location.hash='#/2';     
      else  
      {
        $scope.flag=true;
        $timeout(function(){$scope.flag=false;},3000);
      }
    };

    //the following function creates myService.results array, according to manual clicking on the images, which will be passed to the results page.
    //It is invoking with button Go 
    $scope.results1=function(){
      myService.results=[]; 
      for (var i=0;i<$scope.mychoices.length;i++)
        for (var j=0;j<$scope.photos.length;j++)
        {
          if ( $scope.mychoices[i]===$scope.photos[j].media.m) {
             myService.results.push($scope.photos[j]); 
             break;
          }
        }
      window.location.hash='#/2';
    };

    //collect the chosen, by clicking, photos; more precisely it creates an array with the source paths of the chosen photos
    $scope.mychoices=[];
    $scope.borderize=function(e,sourcephoto){
        if ($(e.currentTarget).closest(".outer-border").css('border-top-width')==='5px') {
           $(e.currentTarget).closest(".outer-border").css('border','1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0)');
           $(e.currentTarget).closest(".outer-border-child").css('height','250px');
           $(e.currentTarget).css('margin-left','0px');
           var index = $scope.mychoices.indexOf(sourcephoto);
           $scope.mychoices.splice(index,1);        //remove a photo if unclicking
        }
        else   {
           $(e.currentTarget).closest(".outer-border").css('border','5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0)');
           $(e.currentTarget).closest(".outer-border-child").css('height','242px');
           $(e.currentTarget).css('margin-left','-3px');
           $scope.mychoices.push(sourcephoto);    //add a photo if clicking
        }
    };
  }]).
  //This is the controller for the results page
  controller('resultsController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope,myService) {
    $scope.photos=myService.results;
    $scope.phototitle=function(title){
        if ($.trim(title).length === 0)
           return "Untitled";
        else if (title.length<=20)
           return title
        else   
           return title.substring(0,20).concat('...');   
    };
    $scope.insertcommas=function(tags){
        var arr=tags.split(' ');
        return arr.join(', ');
    };
  }]).
  //This is a custom directive creating the HTML frame inside which the info for every photo object will be placed 
  directive('myDirective',function(){
      return {
       templateUrl:'frame.html'
    }
  }).
  //This is a custom directive for implementing the infinite scroll
  directive('scrollDirective',function($window){
      return {
        link:function() {
           var AtBottom=true;  
           angular.element($window).on("scroll", function(e){
             e.stopPropagation();      
             e.preventDefault();
             if ((window.innerHeight + document.body.scrollTop) >= document.body.scrollHeight && window.location.hash!=='#/2' && AtBottom)
             {
              AtBottom=false;
                if (window.location.hash=='#/')
                  window.location.hash='#/1'; 
                else
                  window.location.hash='#/';   
             }
           });
        }
     }
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Could you help me by denoting **what points (coding, structure, modularization...) justify the above criticism and how may I ameliorate the above code?** Of course, there are some missing parts (e.g. directives), however you do not need them as to have the general idea.

Comment: All the code that has to do with HTTP calls should be it's own service, which is called from you controller. Also - split up you code into separate files.  I'm no expert but I can probably write a review a little later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright. `it was quite a beginner attempt using Angular`. I would have to agree. There is a number of things you could change:

- Do not put everything in one file (or the `script` tag in your case)
- It's not the controllers job to make $http calls. Use a service.
- Prefer `Controller as` syntax as opposed to `$scope`. [**Explanation here**](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)
- You apply style to elements from your controller. Do that from either a `CSS file` or a `directive`

I'm not going to recreate your example completely, but enough to give you a basic idea on how to structure this better.

I would also recommend using [**John Papa's Angular style guide**](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

**core.js**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);
})();
```

**config.js**

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .config(config);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

    function config($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/',{                        
                templateUrl:'../pages/main.html', 
                controller:'myController',
                controllerAs: 'mc'
            }).
            when('/1',{                   
                templateUrl:'../pages/main.html', 
                controller:'myController',
                controllerAs: 'mc'
            }).
            when('/2',{                    
                templateUrl:'../pages/results.html', 
                controller:'resultsController',
                controllerAs: 'rc'
            }).
            when('/3',{                   
                templateUrl:'../pages/main.html', 
                controller:'myController',
                controllerAs: 'mc'
            });
    }

})();
```

**myService.js**

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .factory('myService', myService);


    myService.$inject = ['$http'];

    function myService($http) {
        var url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK';
        var factory = {
            photos: [],
            getPhotos: getPhotos
        };

        return factory;

        function getPhotos() {
            return $http.jsonp(url)
                .success(handleResponse)
                .error(handleErr);

            function handleResponse(data) {
                factory.photos = retrievePhotoURLs(data);
            }

            function handleErr(err) {
                console.log('Something happened: ' + err);
            }

            //Find img-url
            function retrievePhotoURLs(data) {
                return data.items.map(obj => obj.media.m);
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

**myController.js**

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .controller('myController', myController);


    myController.$inject = ['myService'];

    function myController(myService) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.photos = [];

        //Retrieve the photos

        myService.getPhotos().then(function() {
            vm.photos = myService.photos;
        })
    }

})();
```

**main.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="p in mc.photos">
    <img ng-src="{{p}}">
</div>
```

And the result is some pictures.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
//our main page
...main.html
//our results page
...results.html
```

These seem pretty obvious to me.

*Comments* - ["code tell you how, comments tell you why"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/). The code should speak for itself, if it needs a comment, it might need to be made more clear. If not, the comment should describe *why* you're doing something rather than *how* you're doing it. Here are a [few reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/254979/125931) to avoid comments all together.